# How to Print the filename of the error in Database migration?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am migrating a database from localhost to the azure; the problem is when I run the migration file, it just prints an error, while there are many files that contain the mentioned (in error) table name or column name? How can I print the file name of the error as well?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question, please? Do you have screenshots of the error?

Comment: Thanks, the image added to the question